# ld: duplicate symbol for architecture arm64 is reported for variable template

Tags: c++, arm, clang, specialization, variable-templates

I put the following code into two .cpp's, and cross compiled it with clang on Mac to ARM64 architecture. C++14 was used.

```
template <int>
constexpr bool  Variable = true;

template <>
constexpr bool  Variable<1> = false;
```

I got the following linker error.

```
duplicate symbol 'Variable<1>' in:
    Main.cpp.o
    Other.cpp.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Works fine with other compilers, even with clang when targeting x86-64.

Is this a bug in clang?

Comment: What Clang version?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file are your declarations the same in both files? If not you have an ODR violation. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: @TonyTannous: Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.6).